# How to broadcast errors and warnings in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, socket.io, broadcast, phpwebsocket

I am using Laravel 5.6 and `socket.io` to broadcast messages in admin panel of my application.

In my application, there is a requirement to broadcast all the `errors and warnings` generated before logging them into `laravel logs files` to admin.

I just wanted to know how can I achieve this functionality. What are the other easy ways since I am new to Laravel framework.

This is what I did so far:

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class ErrorBroadcasting implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $errorContent;

    public function __construct($errorContent)
    {
        $this->errorContent = $errorContent;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('error-broadcasting-channel');
    }
}
```

And this is how I am consuming the channel in my blade.

```
<script>

        window.Echo = new Echo({
            broadcaster: 'socket.io',
            host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
        });

        var buyer = Echo.channel(`error-broadcasting-channel`);
        buyer.listen("ErrorBroadcasting", e => {
            $('#error_container').append("<div class=\"row chat-snippet\">\n" +
                "                                        <div class=\"col-lg-12\">\n" +
                "                                            <small>Buyer:</small>\n" +
                "                                            <p>"+e.errorContent+"</p>\n" +
                "                                        </div>\n" +
                "                                    </div>");
        });
</script>
```

And this how I modified my app\Exceptions\Handler.php

```
public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        if (config('app.mail_exception') && $this->shouldReport($exception)) {
            $this->sendEmail($exception); // sends an email
        }
        broadcast(new ErrorBroadcasting($exception))->toOthers();
        parent::report($exception);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your

> app/Exceptions/Handler.php

In this class inside the render method you can

```
 public function report(Exception $exception)
    {

        broadcast($yourEvent)
        parent::report($exception);
    }
```

Comment: @DineshSuthar is the class exists that you are try to broadcast?

Comment: It gives console error: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Comment: Yes the class exists in App\Events\ErrorBroadcasting. My channel is currently public so I think there is no need to create channel entry in `channel.php`

Comment: @DineshSuthar are you using pusher?

Comment: No I am not using pusher, I am using redis and socket.io for broadcasting

Comment: you can remove serialization trait and implement ShouldBroadcast

Comment: @DineshSuthar also do use queable trait

Comment: This is my ErrorBroadcasting.php even class:


`namespace App\Events;`

`use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;`
`use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;`
`use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;`
`use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;`
`use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;`
`use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;`
`use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;`

Comment: @DineshSuthar post the class in the question. It will be much more helpful

Comment: @DineshSuthar did you tried removing SerializesModels trait?

Comment: Yes it gives error now : `{message: "Trait 'App\Events\SerializesModels' not found",…}`

Comment: @DineshSuthar ```use InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels``` to ```use InteractsWithSockets```

Comment: Yes the issue resoved. I have to use `broadcast(new ErrorBroadcasting($exception->getMessage()));` to just to display error message in the html container. Thanks @AdnanMumtaz for your help